# How to get a particular column's values alone?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using the mysql java connector. I need java to display the contents of the first column and the second column in different steps. How do I achieve this?

```
String qry = "select col1,col2 from table1";
Resultset rs = statement.executeQuery(qry);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've posted a sample below:

```
   Statement s = conn.createStatement ();
   s.executeQuery ("SELECT id, name, category FROM animal");
   ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet ();
   int count = 0;
   while (rs.next ())
   {
       int idVal = rs.getInt ("id");
       String nameVal = rs.getString ("name");
       String catVal = rs.getString ("category");
       System.out.println (
               "id = " + idVal
               + ", name = " + nameVal
               + ", category = " + catVal);
       ++count;
   }
   rs.close ();
   s.close ();
   System.out.println (count + " rows were retrieved");
```

(From: http://www.kitebird.com/articles/jdbc.html#TOC_5 )

Edit:  just re-read the question and think you might mean you want to refer to a column later on in code, instead of in the inital loop as in my example above.  In that case, you can create an array and refer to the array later on, or, as another answer suggests you can just do another query.

Comment: +1. I'd like to add that it wouldn't hurt to check for `SQLException`.  For example, `getResultSet()` can throw this. See [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)

Answer (score 0):

Load them into any data structure of your choice and then display them to your heart's content.

```
List<String> firstCol = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> secondCol = new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next()){
   firstCol.add(rs.getString("col1"));
   secondCol.add(rs.getString("col2"));
}
```

Then you can manipulate with the two list as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
String sql = "select col1,col2 from table1";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) System.out.println(rs.getString("col1"));
```

Comment: This will only print the string "col1"

Comment: Oops, me is tired ;) Post edited. If you play with integers, replace `getString()` with `getInt()`

Comment: you actually need to add another rs.getString for col2 for this to work

Answer (score 0):

How about ... (insert drumroll here):

```
String qry1 = "select col1 from table1";
Resultset rs1 = statement.executeQuery(qry);

String qry2 = "select col2 from table1";
Resultset rs2 = statement.executeQuery(qry);
```

(You might want to phrase your question more clearly.)

Comment: Why? Your database is meant to optimize them, it's not just a convenient way of writing and reading data.

Comment: It was a question for my class test.

Answer (score 0):

I am using following Code:

```
Statement sta;
ResultSet rs;
try {
    sta = con.createStatement();
    rs = sta.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        Id = rs.getString("COLUMN_Name1");
        Vid = rs.getString("COLUMN_Name2");
        System.out.println("\n  ID       : " + Id);
        System.out.println("\n  VehicleID: " + Vid);
    }
}
catch(Execption e)
{

}
```

And this code is 100% working.

Answer (score 0):

```
String emailid=request.getParameter("email");
System.out.println(emailid);

rt=st.executeQuery("SELECT imgname FROM selection WHERE email='emailid'");

System.out.println(rt.getString("imgname"));

while(rt.next())
{
    System.out.println(rt.getString("imgname"));
    finalimage=rt.getString("imgname");
}
```

Comment: You should add some description yo your answer to improve it!